# What is expectation for plumber doing finishing work in bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

Last year I worked out a fair price with my plumber to do all the rough-in plumbing for our basement build out that included rough in plumbing work to pass rough-in inspection and it included a return trip to do the finishing work before the final inspection.

I assumed this meant I would provide the fixtures/faucets/valves etc and he would install and hook it all up. When we spoke on the phone, he made it seem like he was expecting me to install all of the faucets and handles and he was simply going to be connecting their pipes to the bottom of the already in-place faucets/handles.

Is this the normal expectation, or should I be leaning on him to install the faucets and handles as well?

Comment: It should have been spelled out in the contract. A good price usually means the homeowner doing some of the easy stuff. So if it is not covered in the contract the good price was you doing some of the work.

Comment: That’s understandable. Good reminder to spell out the minute details, even when in the middle of a very lighthearted/conversational agreement. Thanks for the input

Comment: @EdBeal  That's an answer.. +

Comment: Are you comfortable doing the work? Do you have the tools? If you need a *basin wrench*, that is not something that a typical home owner is going to have. If you can do it yourself, it is probably easier to do it than argue.

Comment: It is easier to mount faucets before vanity top is placed on the cabinets.

Comment: Good point. However it all came pre-attached as one unit so I’m going to have to install normal way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was a bit short but.
It should have been spelled out in the contract. A good price usually means the homeowner doing some of the easy stuff. So if it is not covered in the contract the good price was you doing some of the work. 
As I have been a licensed and bonded contractor I may lean a bit to there side. But there are some real crooks out there and they need to be put out of business. 
This sounds like a mis understanding, and I am sure he will do all the work for a few $ more.